# How to run thor through zeus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thor, zeus

I'd love to run my Thor commands through a Zeus environment. Has anyone managed to do this?

Someone mentioned that you can add a command in a `thor.json` file,
http://railscasts.com/episodes/412-fast-rails-commands?view=comments
but I don't really understand what that means. I can't find any reference to `thor.json` in thor's docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. Run `zeus init` inside your project. This'll create 2 file **which should be ignored in your repository** `zeus.json` & `custom_plan.rb`.

Add `"thor": ["t"]` to the `development_environment` section in `zeus.json`. Then add the following method to the `custom_plan.rb` file:

```
def thor
  require 'thor/runner'
  $thor_runner = true
  Thor::Runner.start
end
```

Now boot up zeus `zeus start` and in another terminal type `zeus t -T` to see the list of thor commands.